# How to install gfortran-4.6 or gcc-4.6 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gcc, fortran

I have recently upgraded my work computer to ubuntu 20.04 and I have code that specifically requires gfortran-4.6 to run. How can I install gfortran-4.6 either alongside the newest gfrotran or as separate user that runs gfortran-4.6 while still having a user account that runs the newer gfortran? I previously found a work around for this by installing an older ppa repository, but that was a few years ago and I have not been able to find information about it by searching the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to meet my needs by simply adding the following lines to my /etc/apt/sources.list file (based on the answer by N0rbert):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then I could update and install gfortran-4.6 with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.6
```

I now have both the most recent gfortran that is default for Ubuntu 20.04 alongside gfortran-4.6 and have not found any conflicts so far.

Answer (score 0):

This fortran version was available in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I can suggest to create [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) with 14.04 LTS and install old fortran here:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/trusty.conf
[trusty]
description=Ubuntu 14.04
directory=/srv/chroot/trusty
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/trusty
sudo debootstrap trusty /srv/chroot/trusty

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/trusty/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c trusty -u root apt-get update
schroot -c trusty -u root apt-get install software-properties-common sudo
schroot -c trusty -u root apt-get install gcc-4.6 gfortran-4.6
```

Then execute your program inside the schroot by using command like:

```
schroot -c trusty /home/user/old-program
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to solve my problem because the software I am trying to run has other dependencies on programs that are not available for Ubuntu 14.04. I need to be able to run gfortran-4.6 within the context of newer programs. In particular, I need to run the newest version of Mercurial, which I cannot do from within the schroot trusty shell created from this code.